# The jump and the left martingale of semimartingale

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $X_{t}$ be a semimartingale.  Define 
   $\Delta X_{t} = X_{t}- X_{t-}$.
For fixed $s> 0$, $\Delta X_{s}$ and $X_{s-}$ are two random variable.  Are they independent to each other? I think the answer is yes. But I am not sure the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $W_t$ be 1-dimensional Brownian motion and let
$$V_t=W_t+\sum_{n\in\mathbb N,\, n\le t} W_n$$
Then
\begin{eqnarray}
\Delta V_n&=&W_n,\quad\text{whereas}\\
V_{n-}&=&\sum_{m\in\mathbb N,\, m\le n} W_m
\end{eqnarray}
so $\Delta V_n$ and $V_{n-}$ are not independent of eachother.

Comment: Levy processes would be different

Comment: I got this. In the case of Levy process it is true. More generally, this conclusion is ture for additive process. We only need the increment $X_{t}-X_{s}$ is independent of $X_{s}$.